# Concurrency between threads without locks?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, operating-system, thread-safety

I was asked how to achieve concurrency between threads without using locks, given unlimited memory. I tried looking it up but can't find an answer that doesn't use any locks. This should be possible...

Comment: Voting to close as not a question, you should google `lock-free programming` though.

Comment: I don't understand why this isn't a question. The question is "how can you achieve concurrency between threads without using locks, given unlimited memory?". As in, what scheme would be used? How would reads and writes work?

Comment: If that's the question, you should put that question in your question.

Comment: The problem usually isn't concurrency; a modern multi-core CPU provides that.  The issue is usually synchronization between the threads while they are sharing the same memory, which is a much harder problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most modern CPUs support a set of atomic operations that can be used to coordinate access to data without locks (those CPU instructions are often used to implement locking library functions).  For example, Sun Ultrasparcs have a Compare-And-Swap (CAS) instruction: to use it you first read a memory address normally into a CPU register, then calculate the desired new value, then use CAS - specifying the original and new values; if and only if the memory content is still the original value will the new value be written into that memory.  So this doesn't prevent race conditions from causing your update attempt to fail, but it lets you detect that failure then work out what to do about it.  Typically, you loop and try again - first reading whatever value some other thread wrote into that memory while you were calculating your new value and attempting the update.

That may be a bit confusing, so let's take a more concrete example.  Say you need to count the number of operations completed by all your threads - you can set the counter to 0 before the threads start, then have each thread use `do { read/add-1/CAS } while (failure)` logic to increment the counter.

Comment: My main confusion: If you check the value and it has been updated since your last read, you loop. How is it possible for the value to not have been updated on the next iteration? Am I misunderstanding what we're doing on the next iteration? Are we still reading the same value? Or maybe a different version of it?

Comment: Multi-core CPUs implement a [cache coherence protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESI) which ensures that writes and reads to cache lines will be coherent across cores. Usually it's the compiler's job to translate your language's memory model into the CPU's memory model so you don't have to worry too much about that.

Comment: @ZeBlob: often, but it does depend which system you work on.  For example - Sun workstations may have multiple CPUs, and explicit machine code instructions act as memory barriers to coordinate specified synchronisation.  In the case of C++03, there's no mention of thread safety and the programmer needs to be aware of their system's and compiler's behaviours.

Comment: @user1136342: yes - you're misunderstanding.  Let's go more explicitly through the incrementing a shared counter example: the logic is basically `do { int proposed = shared_counter + 1; success = cas(shared_counter, proposed); } while (!success);`.  If another thread updates between the read of `shared_counter` in `proposed = ...`, then `cas` will fail and you'll loop to read the updated `shared_counter` - it may incorporate any number of increments from any number of other threads, but you'll get the current value then if you win the race to update it, you can continue.

Answer (score 0):

It is completely possible and quite trivial, provided the threads either:

- Don't share any data
  OR
- Share data, but only read from the shared piece of data and don't write to it.

However, once writing to shared data comes into the picture, things get complicated. This is where you need to [start reading up](http://www.1024cores.net/home/lock-free-algorithms/introduction).

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at software transactional memory (STM). Instead of locking, threads can update shared memory through transactions which can be checked for conflicts.